# How can /dev/sd* be mounted directly after rebooting?

Tags: centos, partition, lvm, network-interface, disk

I executed the command `fdisk /dev/sd*` and start partionning the disk. I set a new partition file system, then mounted the new partition to a directory that I created. For boot-up automatic running  I edited the file `/etc/fstab`. Here is the problem, when I reboot. I cannot find my network interface: my network system is inactive (dead). I don't know why and how?

Comment: This sounds like two unrelated questions.  Are there errors in the boot logs?

Comment: If to questions, then ask them seperatly.

Comment: @user10489 everything is fine when I add a line in /etc/fstab, but right after I reboot, my network system is inactive (dead).

Comment: Does the network come back if you comment out the line in fstab and reboot?   If you then uncomment the line, can you mount the filesystem by the directory name (relying on the fstab info to actually find it)?